# Axis2 WSDL2java is generating only 2 java classes

Tags: web-services

**I am using Axis2 for developing webservices** .

**Please see my program below :**

```
public class Simple {

    public String echo(String rest) {

        return rest;
    }

}
```

**After deploying into Axis2.war , i got this wsdl file generated**

**Client code generation using wsdl2java :**

After generating the wsdl file , i used wsdl2java for genertaing the client code

**C:>WSDL2Java.bat -uri http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/SimpleService?wsdl -
o E:\Axis2Tutorial\Examples\HelloWorld\client**

**After i ran this command i got only 2 files geerated :**

```
SimpleServiceCallbackHandler
SimpleServiceStub
```

**Now my question is that , why only 2 files are being that is SimpleServiceCallbackHandler and SimpleServiceStub 
(Where as in some of thr Axis2 Client class i have also seen Response class ) why is this  in not my case .**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default those classes are generated within the stub file. You can use `-u` option to generate separate data binding classes. Please see [here](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/reference-guide-axis2-code-generation-parameters-part-1) for more information.