# Problems referencing WSDL2Java generated classes

Tags: java, playframework, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I'm having a problem referencing and using the classes generated by WSDL2Java (for reference this is a follow on question from here: [Java out of memory errors on large WSDLs (play framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633099/java-out-of-memory-errors-on-large-wsdls-play-framework/9739513#9739513)). Depending on how I try to reference the files it generates I get different errors when I run it. (Note: I just get these errors during runtime)

So, I run my WSDL2Java (with XMLBeans option) and then use ants to build it. After I've generated and built my classes I get the 3 standard folders and build file:

- build
- resources
- src
- build.xml

This contains all the good stuff. Next, within my project in Eclipse I've created a folder called ***dynamics*** and added the above 3 folders to it. To use the classes (without compile errors) I can simply add ***dynamics/build/classes*** to my buildpath/classpath. Note: in eclipse it seems a bit clunky to figure out the right way to add something to the class path... The way I initially tried this was:

`Project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Add Class Folder`

Another way was using:

`Run -> Run Configurations -> Classpath`

Neither way seems to make a difference. But either way I seem to be able to use my WSDL code and everything looks fine. But when I try to run it I hit some problems. Solely doing the above referencing I get the following error when I hit a webservice on my webapp:

`The file /app/controllers/Application.java could not be compiled. Error rasied is : com.microsoft.schemas.xrm._2011.contracts.Entity cannot be resolved`

So, to get around this, another thing I've tried is adding all of the generated source to my projects source folder. Basically take ALL of the WSDL generated .java files in ***dynamics/src*** and paste it into my ***project/app*** (basically where all of my project source code lives). This way gets me a lot further. I hit a webservice of my project, it in turn attempts to call a dynamics webservice (using the dynamics WSDL stuff)... and it's fine right up until I try to use an object that references XMLBeans object, which is when I hit my next error, which is:

`Cannot load SchemaTypeSystem. Unable to load class with name schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.<*really long id*>.TypeSystemHolder`

So basically, it will let me generate my OrganizationServiceStub, but as soon as I try to run a request (e.g. RetrieveMultiple) it hits me with the above error.

Any ideas? Help very much appreciated!

**A few details:**

- I'm trying to reference this using Eclipse
- Using the XMLBeans option when running WSDL2Java
- Axis2 version 1.5.4
- Built using Apache ant 1.8.3
- Using PlayFramework
- Generating from a MS Dynamics WSDL (very large definition!)

---

**Update**

I've noticed that if I add the WSDL generated .java files as a new source folder (rather than copy/pasting all the .java files into my main project source folder) it gives this error:

`The file /app/controllers/Application.java could not be compiled. Error rasied is : com.microsoft.schemas.xrm._2011.contracts.Entity cannot be resolved`

This is a different error than if I copy and paste the source files... which seems odd to me...